# Check New Route on componentWillUnmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some code that will run on `componentWillUnmount()` but I only want it run if they go back to the previous page. If they go forward to the next page I don't want what is inside the `componentWillUnmount` to run.

I am using React Router 4 but when I check it in the `componentWillUnmount` it still has not updated to whatever the next url is.

```
  componentWillUnmount() {
    const props = this.props;
    const location = props.location;

  }
```

Comment: when you say back, do you mean if they hit the browser back button or do you have a button/link explicitly go backwards e.g. like in a menu/breadcrumbs or something?

Comment: same question than @TomFinney for next page when you say "If they go forward to the next page ". Is this through the next page button in the browser navbar, or through HTML element ?

Comment: @TomFinney - I have both. Going forward is just a button on the site.

Answer (score 2):

React Router provides a [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#blocking-transitions) object which you can use to set some variables before the transition to a new location.

Try something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.history.block((location, action) => {
        this.isGoingBack = action === 'POP';
    })
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.isGoingBack) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You might need to check the `location` aswell.

Comment: ah so I got to do my own check basically?